# Must a patch panel be initially terminated in the rack?

Tags: networking, cable, physical-environment, rack, infrastructure

If Cat6 Ethernet cables were terminated to a wall mounted patch panel, is there a method to move the patch panel to a rack (without having to cut them and reterminate them)?

Is a patch panel coupled to the rack, so that you need to have your rack in place when you terminate your cables to the patch panel, and have the patch panel in the other side? Is there a way to switch racks without having to reterminate everything?

If you have a patch panel, is there any good way to change racks or add a rack for the first time?

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear. If it helps, the patch panel in the rack is typically a 1u block which can be unscrewed and mounted anywhere in the rack (or removed from the rack and put into another if allowed by the cabling.

Comment: Cabling in wall and going to the back of a patch panel is punched down and solid core while Ethernet leads are stranded core and not designed to be punched down, so it would not be a good idea to try to have rj45 on one side and punch the other. You could possibly have 2 rj45 patch panels, patch leads to on and the wall and jumper between them but you would probably get a more robust connection with less work reterminating the wiring straight into the patch panel if length allows.